# Имена всех свойств параметров в приложении

Tags: c#, winforms

Как получить все имена свойств параметров приложения?
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (SettingsProperty currentProperty in Properties.Settings.Default.Properties)  
{  
     Console.WriteLine(currentProperty.Name);
}
```